# Save Dialog Box In Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, save

I am generating PDF in netbeans and that part is okay as far as requirements are concerned.
My manager added that they may choose where they could save the generated pdf.
How to do it in netbeans? There will be a dialog box where user may choose directory where to save the generated pdfs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) For a working example to get you started.

Comment: Yeah I got it, But it should not open a file. The system is asking where to save the generated pdf. Is is seeking for a path where to save the pdf

Comment: @user2028185, Did you read the tutorial? Did you try the example? It doe not open a file, it only asks you to select the file name. It is then up to you to save your file in the directory selected by the user.

Comment: Yeah. I need an example that don't need to specify a filename. It should ask where to save the pdf generated by the system.

Comment: I solved it already, I edited the dialogtype into save_dialog and the fileselectionmode into directories_only. Anyway, thank you for spending time on my questin. :)

Comment: @user2028185, What do you mean you solved it? The tutorial shows you how to do this. That was the point of reading the tutorial. The FileChooserDemo shows you how to do this which is why I suggested you read the tutorial and try the example. There is even a button titled "Save a File" for you to look at. The tutorial also gives example code to show the save dialog and for selecting directories only.

Comment: Yes I agree. The tutorial shows how to save a file into a directory chosen by the user. But what I need is to ask for a directory where to save the generated pdf. No more typing or overwriting a file.